# Loop function until response is OK or error is persistent

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to wrap an API request function in a loop to repeat the request in case of error OR give up if the error is persistent. I came up with this

```
let data;
let all_ok = false;
let counter = 0;
do {
  data = await getDataAPI(token_id);
  counter++;
  if (! await checkAPIerrors(data)) { // something bad happened
    await sleep(5000);
  } else {
    all_ok = true;
  }
  if (counter > 10) {
    throw "getDataAPI error"; // stop execution, there is a serious problem
  }
} while (!all_ok);
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, perhaps with promises or callback functions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not a recursive approach?

```js
let counter = 0
const getDataAPI = () => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(counter < 5 ? rej : res, 2000))
const sleep = (t) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t))

const fetchRecursively = async(id) => {
  counter++
  try {
    const data = await getDataAPI(id);
    console.log("Success!", id)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("FAILED, retrying in 5 seconds... ", 5 - counter, " attempts left.")
    await sleep(5000)
    fetchRecursively(id)
  }
}

fetchRecursively(123)
```

I'm just simulating a rejection with a counter, but in your real world case, as long as your `getDataAPI` service rejects, it's going to retry until your catch block catches the rejection.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm looking for a synchronous solution.
What is the advantage of this method?
Honestly I find Promises very confusing, so I tend to avoid them. In your example, the 'res' function where the actual processing would take place if everything is OK, is a completely separate function, correct?

Comment: Also, what happens if the Promise is rejected when counter = 5? I would need the script execution to stop, because it would mean something very serious was happening and there would be no point in continuing without checking for the underlying causes.

Comment: In your example you are actually using promises and asynchronouse code, since you are using `await` keyword. Every time you execute a function declared with `async` you are just executing a Promise, since every async function returns a Promise. That's why you **need** to wrap the content inside a try/catch block ,otherwise you won't catch the rejections. In your example you are retrieving data, then use the data to check if there was an error, that looks a pretty weird behaviour, do you have multi thread job on server that you can't await the response directly  to check for errors ?

Comment: My example is pretty straightforward, if the API call for some reason rejects on server (validation errors, DB interaction error, etc...) it gets directly into the catch block and keeps retrying, until it hits the max counter value that you can set manually inside the catch block. If no error occurs, you can do whatever operation you want with data, just below the api call.

Comment: I use await for 2 specific cases, 1 is because the fetch function is asynchronous and I would like requests to the API server to be synchronous, so I can register the result in order and also because there is a rate limit and this way it forces the script to naturally wait for the response before sending another one and optimize the server's own management of the rate limit without abusive request rates or unnecessary delays. The 2nd case is just that in case of error, I introduce a longer delay and that sleep function is a Promise.

Comment: HTTP requests are never synchronous, whether you use xhr, standard promises or async/await to perform a fetch. Don't be fooled by the bheaviour you have inside an async function. That might look synchronous code. Writing: `await doThis(); await doThat();` is just the same of writing `dothis().then(doThat)` and in both cases that code will be executed asynchronously in respect to the code that is executing on the main thread. I understand what you are doing, just don't understand why you need to make a second call to check if there were errors instead of receiving them with the first call.

Comment: I was about to explain this, but it will become a different topic about the architecture/logic of the rest of the code and would require introducing information beyond this particular check loop. I actually would like to discuss it, maybe with a flowchart and some skeleton code, is there a place for that? Stackoverflow or perhaps another 'stack' website?

 I will run some tests with your suggestion to try and understand it better. For example I still don't understand if the promise is rejected after the 5 failed attempts, is the script stopped altogether?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244371/discussion-between-cesare-polonara-and-user2066480).